# Unable to RDP into windows?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I have a windows 16 machine on AWS. I installed Cygwin on it so that I can connect it as a jenkins slave. But once I connected it as a slave, I am NOT able to MSTSC/RDP into the machine. I can still access the machine via ssh/cygwin.

( I repeated the process several times and ended up losing rdp connectivity everytime )

This is what is actually happening now :

1. The EventLogs on machine are saying that logoff instructions are being initiated by the RDP client.
2. RDP client is saying "The disconnection was initiated by the user logging off their session on the server"
3. Visually, if seems like the remote connection was setup for a split second. Then it vanishes.

So, I believe that somehow my Administrator account is not able to maintain the session. It's getting disconnected as soon as it connects.

Can you suggest me which settings should I debug into ? I am able to extract a few details from my machine using ssh, but I can't explore all the settings.

**If you are familiar with this behaviour please suggest me what settings might be reponsible for this.**

Addition info:

1. If I restart my ec2 , it will never come back because a status check starts failing
2. I am able to telnet to 3389 port. So I guess, firewall rules are not an issue.
3. I have tried various RDP clients, on MAC as well as on Windows.
4. I found this in event log (ProviderName: Microsoft-Windows-RemoteDesktopServices-RdpCoreTS) on my remote windows machine:

```
5/10/2019 3:13:44 PM           103 Information      The disconnect reason is 12   
.
.
.
5/10/2019 3:13:43 PM           228 Warning          Disconnect trace:CUMRDPConnection Disconnect trace:'calling spGfxPlugin->PreDisconnect()' in CUMRDPConnection::PreDisconnect at 4477 err=[0xc], Error code:0xC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the my problem was occuring due to some cleanup utility deleting up the system files required for mstsc.
Everything started working fine after I switched off the cleanup utility.
Thanks for the help though.